# Java wrong output in (Fahrenheit to celsius conversion program) !

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer

*I have an assignment which is* 
**Write a program that converts a Fahrenheit degree to Celsius using formula:
Celsius = (5/9)(Fahrenheit - 32)**

The problem is I am always getting the same value -17.78 whatever I give value in input.

Here down there is my code !!!

```
package com.temperatureconversion;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class TemperatureConversion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double F = 0.0;    // Temperature in Fahrenheit
    double C = 0.0;          // Temperature in celsius
    C = 5.0 /9 * (F - 32);

    System.out.print("Enter temperature in fahrenheit: ");
    F = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.printf("The celsius value of %10.2f is %2.2f", F, C);




}

}
```

What's wrong with the above code ?

Comment: You need to ask for the value `F` before doing your calculations. This is not Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `F` value is always the same `0.0`, because you're asking for its value after your calculations, so you need to move the getting of `F` value before doing calculation.

```
double F = 0.0;    // Temperature in Fahrenheit
double C = 0.0;          // Temperature in celsius

//ASK for value.
System.out.print("Enter temperature in fahrenheit: ");
F = input.nextDouble();

// Do your calculations.
C = 5.0 /9 * (F - 32);
```

Comment: But what about the declaration of variables like F and C ?

Comment: You are welcome, and please don't forget to accept it as answer if its solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this , ask first and then calculate

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

double F = 0.0;    // Temperature in Fahrenheit
double C = 0.0;          // Temperature in celsius


System.out.print("Enter temperature in fahrenheit: ");
F = input.nextDouble();
C = 5.0 /9 * (F - 32);
System.out.printf("The celsius value of %10.2f is %2.2f", F, C);
```

}